# adding TCP Jersey on NS2

Tags: agent, adhoc, ns2

I'd like to implement TCP Jersey in Manet environment https://web.njit.edu/anl/download.html, but not sure how to add droptail code to NS2 because naturally, a router is not exist in Manet. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No router? ... Manet examples, all have `$ns_ node-config -routerTrace ON `  →  manet-examples-2.tar.gz → https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNR0ZuQ1l6YnlWRGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I mean there is no dedicated router like a typical wireless network. every node can serve as a router. anw, how can I implement droptail of TCP Jersey in NS2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP NJ : drop-tail.cc, drop-tail.h are here https://web.njit.edu/anl/download.html

Some of the files are old. I did my tests with ns-2.29 → ns-allinone-2.29.3.tar.gz

Added to `tcl/lib/ns-default.tcl`, line 104 - 111 some Queue/DropTail (random) values ... (I guess you know some better settings) :

```
# Added for TCP NJ ====================
Queue/DropTail set curq_ 20
Queue/DropTail set ave_ 5
Queue/DropTail set q_weight_ 2
Queue/DropTail set dropped_ 0
Queue/DropTail set arrived_ 10
Queue/DropTail set idle_pktsize_ 1
# =====================================
```

The example `sample.tcl` : `$ ns sample-NR.tcl NJ 0.001` : OK.

TCP westwood files :  http://c3lab.poliba.it/Westwood:NS2

My files: TCP-jersey-westwood_ns229.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSDR0c0Z3bGVNenM/view?usp=sharing

The simulation examples : TCP-jersey-westwood_examples.tar.gz 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNV0hlOEpuTGVYeWM/view?usp=sharing

---

EDIT: A patch for ns-2.35 was created → TCP-jersey-westwood_ns235.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSDhIT3FDNE85SEk/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < TCP-jersey-westwood_ns235.patch
./install
```

It's a little tricky, two old files require g++-3.4.6 : When `./install` stops: `cd ns-2.35/` ... edit the Makefile to `CPP = g++34` and run `make` for a little while. Edit the Makefile back to `CPP = g++` , and finish `make`. I.e. g++34 cannot compile the last files.

`g++34` is available for the most OS: Fedora, CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu, etc.  Please ask for a link if e.g. Ubuntu.

Comment: Answer edited 'Jun 18 2017' : Added `TCP-jersey-westwood_ns235.patch`, etc.